# How to merge 4 adjacent, coplanar faces into a single face

Tags: modeling

I have a plane consisting of 4 squares - take as an example a subdivided plane. How can I merge these faces into one?

Comment: Dissolve the middle vertecis of each edge and the middle vertex, by pressing [x]> Dissolve vertices

Comment: @X-27 Feel free to put a link here if you are unsure, or vote to close.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is an operator called Dissolve which does exactly what you want.

Select everything, with <kbd>A</kbd>, and then press <kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>Delete</kbd>) and select `Limited dissolve`. This will do the same thing as above, but will not require you to select the proper vertices manually.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

so long as the faces are surrounded by more geometry, using <kbd>f</kbd> for Make Edge/Face works well.  For a whole simple sub-divided plane like the example given, this tool will make a mess.

[image]

Comment: This does recuce reduce the poly-count (check the triangle count in the header)

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is sometime more efficient to use <kbd>x</kbd> in edit mode then **Disolve edge**.

Let's convert this curve into mesh with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>:

[image]

You end up with the following mesh.

[image]

This mesh will be hard to process because it has holes. for example, <kbd>f</kbd> simply doesn't work. Using **Limited disolve** will not work well too, here is the best result I can get using this method :

[image]

**Disolve edge** is interesting because you can process the mesh multiple times without changing the whole shape. Here is the result I obtain after two **Disolve Edge** :

[image]