# How do I remove redundant triangles?

Tags: geometry

I finished creating my mesh, and one of the faces looks like this:

[image]

But then when I export it, instead it ends up looking more like this:

[image]

Now, I'm aware that this face is not really a rectangle and Blender provides a convenient layer of abstraction between me and actual vertices/triangles. But clearly you could have two triangles here instead of ten. How do I get rid of them? If I press "f", they can be merged into a single rectangle, but pressing ctrl+t turns them into this mess again. I tried many things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: To which format do you export? Some might only be able to handle triangles.

Comment: .fbx, and yes, I want triangles, but this huge rectangle should be divided into two, not ten.

Comment: The initial rectangle probably isnt' a quad, but a Ngon. How many vertices are there in its boundary?

Comment: Yeah, there are actually more vertices than 4. How do I merge them now?

Comment: You could try to first triangulate the face and then use a limited dissolve on it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20920/how-to-merge-4-adjacent-coplanar-faces-into-a-single-face/20921#20921

Comment: Thanks a lot - I used dissolve on vertices, just had to select the redundant ones and it did what I wanted!